# android Handler sendMessage order

Tags: android, multithreading, handler

is it possible for a handler in Main thread to receive Message A first and Message B second if I send Message B and then Message A in another one single thread?

I mean:
In sub thread a:

`hander.sendMessage(B);
hander.sendMessage(A);`

and in Main thread, could it be possible for handler to receive A first and B second?

Comment: sendMessageAtFrontOfQueue ?

Comment: @pskink e...what do you mean?

Comment: you want to change the order of the messages, right? or you just asking if the order can be somehow changed by. the system?

Comment: @pskink  I don't want to change the order, I'm just asking if the order can be changed

Comment: I must make sure some work be done in a right order, so I'm wondering if the order may be changed by system

Comment: no it cannot, if you use sendMessage the Messages are placed in a FIFO queue

Comment: @pskink  thx~ how can I accept your answer?